# How to print only tasks that declared in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to print(using cmd) **only** tasks that have been declared in `build.gradle` by me?

Command `gradle tasks` prints a lot of other tasks.

Example output of `gradle tasks`:

```
Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build.
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files.

Help tasks
----------
buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project '1.07-Exercise-ConfigureATask'.
components - Displays the components produced by root project '1.07-Exercise-ConfigureATask'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project '1.07-Exercise-ConfigureATask'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project '1.07-Exercise-ConfigureATask'.
dependentComponents - Displays the dependent components of components in root project '1.07-Exercise-ConfigureATask'. [incubating]
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project '1.07-Exercise-ConfigureATask'. [incubating]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project '1.07-Exercise-ConfigureATask'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project '1.07-Exercise-ConfigureATask'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project '1.07-Exercise-ConfigureATask'.
```

Comment: There isn't a way, but you could put them all in the same `group` to visually group them. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just want to filter out my own tasks. It's not convenient to see all these tasks that aren't related to my build script.